# Placing 1d items in a 2d grid with constraints

Tags: algorithm, search

I'M looking for an algorithm (preferably polynomial) for the following problem:

Input:
- an M x N grid, where each square can be either empty or occupied
- a list of items
- a list of constraints

Output:
the grid, such that all items are placed and the constraints aren't violated.

Each item is a 1d block of length k. Different items may have different length, and there may be several items with the same length. Items can't ovelap each other.

Example 1:
Given 1 x 5 grid and 2 items of lengths 1, 2 respectively. The following solutions are acceptable:

11100

10110

11010

and so forth.

Example 2:
Given 3 x 5 grid and 2 items of lengths 1, 2 respectively. The following solutions are acceptable:

00110
10000
00000

11000
10000
00000

etc.

Possible constraints:
a. Isolation - items may not touch each other. e.g. the following solutions is illegal:

Example 1:

11100

Example 2:

11000
10000
00000

However this is a legal solution:

01100
10000
00000

i.e. touching diagonals are legal.

b. Facing - 2 items must be placed one in front of the other. e.g.

11000
00000
11000

What I did so far is to find a solution for a simpler problem, where the grid is 1d and the only possible constraint is Isolation. I solved it by representing it as a search problem, and using A* with the heuristic: sum of lengths of items not placed yet.The problem is that it suffers from state explosion which will only deteriorate in higher dimensions.

Comment: I would try this: sort the items by length. place as many as possible in the first row of the grid. constraint a. should be easy. 

You can also use a evolutionary algorithm but if you have many items and a small grid the algorithm may not find a solution.

Comment: Thanks, how would you deal with the Facing constraint? currently it's my main difficulty

Comment: actually i did not understand this point^^

Comment: The constarint basically says that 2 items showld b aligned, i.e. their left corners are on the same column and distanced 2 from each other.

Comment: ok. it seems to me the best you see such two elements as one and place them together. as they need together more space as other elements the should placed first